# Determine Correct Oracle Constructor (ORA-06550/PLS-00306 error)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Oracle 11g

I am having trouble determining the correct constructor for a record of a table I've created.  I keep getting a ORA-06550/PLS-00306 error combination for each argument.

For example, an example table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_EXAMPLE_TABLE
(
  ID        NUMBER(8)                 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FK_ID     NUMBER(8)                 NOT NULL,
  SOME_DATA NUMBER(8)   
)
TABLESPACE MyTablespace;
```

I try to instantiate a record as follows:

```
DECLARE
      TYPE example_rec_tab IS TABLE OF TMP_EXAMPLE_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
      example_recs example_rec_tab;  
  BEGIN
    example_recs.EXTEND;
    example_recs(example_recs.COUNT) := example_rec_tab(1, 2, 3);
  END;
```

But I get

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 41:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXAMPLE_REC_TAB'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 41:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXAMPLE_REC_TAB'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 41:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXAMPLE_REC_TAB'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I don't see what is wrong here, and more generally, I would like to know how to determine the correct constructor for any record that I am trying to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`example_rec_tab(1, 2, 3)` is trying to create a *table*, not a single record. You need to populate the individual fields of the record; and you need to instantiate the table before you start:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE example_rec_tab IS TABLE OF TMP_EXAMPLE_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
  example_recs example_rec_tab;
BEGIN
  example_recs := example_rec_tab();
  example_recs.EXTEND;
  example_recs(example_recs.COUNT).id := 1;
  example_recs(example_recs.COUNT).id := 2;
  example_recs(example_recs.COUNT).id := 3;
END;
/
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89cb4).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE 
      SUBTYPE my_row_type IS TMP_EXAMPLE_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
      TYPE example_rec_tab IS TABLE OF my_row_type;
      example_recs example_rec_tab;  
      my_row my_row_type;
  BEGIN
    example_recs := example_rec_tab();
    example_recs.EXTEND;
    SELECT 1 , 2 , 3  INTO my_row FROM dual;
    example_recs(example_recs.COUNT) := my_row ;
  END;
/
```